# How can I check from a plugin config file if devMode is enabled?

Tags: plugin-development, config, php, plugin-contactform, devmode

Using the Pixel & Tonic [Contact Form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) plugin, I added a config file (`config/contactform.php`) to override plugin settings from the CP.

I would like to change some settings if devMode is enabled : recipients from the contact form plugin, to separate my tests addresses from my client addresses.

```
<?php

$recipients = array(
    'devMode' => 'example@domain.com,example@domain.com',
    'prodMode' => 'john@doe.com,jean@dupont.com'
);

if (devMode == true) {
    $recipients = $recipients['devMode'];
} else {
    $recipients = $recipients['prodMode'];
}

return array(
    'toEmail' => ($recipients ?: null),
```

How can I check if **devMode == true**? Can I access to this value using `craft()->config` or something else that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
if ( craft()->config->get( 'devMode' ) )
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Using this, I get this error : `The property « Craft\ConfigService.devMode » is undefined.`. Yes, I'm using environment variables, but following the other answer there is no devMode data that I can get from `the craft()->config->get('environmentVariables')`, while devMode is enabled in my current dev environment.

Comment: This is because you're not in the Craft namespace. Included in most files is a `namespace Craft;` declaration at the top of the file, but in config files this is not usually there. You could either add this namespace declaration to your config file, or use `\Craft\craft()->config->devMode` instead.

Comment: `namespace Craft;` was already specified at the first line of my config/contactform.php file.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution : craft()->config->get('devMode') does the job. Thank you !

Comment: Oh I see, I misread the original error. I'm pretty sure you need to use `craft()->config->get('devMode')` instead

Comment: Good spot - will update my answer.

Comment: @LukePearce I think you're confusing Multi-Environment configuration and the [`environmentVariables`](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) config setting.

Comment: I sure am. I'm tempted to just delete my answer and let someone else take care of it! ha

Comment: Please, don’t! You well deserve the points for all this answer maintenance work, heh?!

Answer (score 14):

For those coming here using Craft 3, it's now `Craft::$app->getConfig()->general->devMode`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Craft 4.0, the recommended method to test if Craft is running in [dev mode](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/what-dev-mode-does) from the PHP layer is [`App::devMode()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-helpers-app.html#public-methods):

```php
use craft\helpers\App;

$devMode = App::devMode();
```

Apart from `App::devMode()` being faster (and less verbose to type), the big difference between it and `Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->devMode` is that the latter will simply return whatever value the [`devMode` config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#devmode) is currently set to, whereas `App::devMode()` will tell you *if Craft is actually running in dev mode or not*, by returning the value for the `YII_DEBUG` constant.

In practice, the values for the `devMode` config setting and the `YII_DEBUG` constant will almost always be the same - but not necessarily, and there are edge cases where the nuance between the two can make a difference.

Internally, Craft uses `App::devMode()` in most cases.

If working in Twig, `App::devMode()` is not available, but the global [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/global-variables.html#devmode) variable can be used instead, which will return the same thing (i.e. the `YII_DEBUG` constant's value):

```
{% if devMode %}
   We are debuggin'
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here >= Craft 3.5, it's now

```
Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->devMode.
```